# Return an object with properties for each of the word in the wordlist

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to implement a frequency function which should return an object with properties for each of the words in the wordlist. The values of the properties should be how many times the word is present in text. I am able to only return the number of counts, but I could not figure out how to return an object. The answer should be an object like {"bar": 2, "foo": 3}.

```
function frequencies(str,wordlist){

    var count = 0;
    var count2 = 0;
    var freqw = {};
    var text1 = str.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < wordlist.length; i++){
        if(str.match(wordlist[i]))
         count++;
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(frequencies('foo foo bar foo   bar buz', ['foo', 'bar']));
```

Comment: Instead of a single `count`, maybe use an object with words as keys and counts as values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use indexOf instead of match and also loop over the input string instead of the wordlist

```
function frequencies(str,wordlist){

    var count = 0;
    var count2 = 0;
    var freqw = {};
    var text1 = str.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < wordlist.length; i++){
        freqw[wordlist[i]] = 0;

    }

    for(var i = 0; i < text1.length; i++){
        if(freqw[text1[i]] !== undefined)  //check if word exists
            freqw[[text1[i]]]++;
    }
    return freqw;
}

console.log(frequencies('foo foo bar foo   bar buz', ['foo', 'bar']));
```

Comment: thanks it working. just need to know in the first loop why freqw[wordlist[i]]=0 each time the loop run....?

Comment: To initialize the counts

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the wordlist, and count occurences by just splitting on each word

```js
function frequencies(str,wordlist){
    return wordlist.reduce( (a,b) => {
     return a[b] = str.split(new RegExp('\\b'+b+'\\b','g')).length-1,a;
    },{})
}

console.log(frequencies('foo foo bar foo   bar buz', ['foo', 'bar']));
```

Comment: Would not splitting the array everytime affect the performance

Comment: @ankit31894 - no more so than matching it with a regex every time, or splitting the wordlist and iterating over six words rather than the two in the wordlist etc.

Comment: But it has a little glitch that it is looking for substring instead of words

Answer (score 0):

You can accumulate counts for each word in an object.

Something like:

```
function frequencies(str, wordlist) {
    let words = str.split(' ');
    let count = {};
    words.forEach(function(word) {
        if (wordList.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
            if (!count[word]) count[word] = 0;
            count[word] += 1;
        }
    });
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using `Sring.prototype.match`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

What I am doing is simply loop through all given values and finc a match in given text. I am using case insenstive match but if you want case senstive match remove `i` flag in regular expression.

```
function getFrequency(text, inputs) {
  var result = {};
  inputs.forEach(function(input){
    var reg = new RegExp(input, 'gi');
    result[input] = text.match(reg).length
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getFrequency('foo foo bar foo   bar buz', ['foo', 'bar']));
```

Comment: I like the regex. :-)

Comment: @JimBaldwin I like as well but I don't know much about this, just some simple rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
function frequencies(str,wordlist){

    var count = 0;
    var count2 = 0;
    var freqw = {};
    var arr = str.split(' ');


    var item = {};
    var result = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < wordlist.length; i++){
      var frecuencies = [];
      frecuencies = arr.filter(function (item) {
        return (item == wordlist[i]);
      });

      if (frecuencies.length > 0) {
        result.push({item: frecuencies[0], count: frecuencies.length});
      }


      console.log(frecuencies);
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(frequencies('foo foo bar foo bar buz', ['foo', 'bar']));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function frequencies(str, wordlist) {
  return wordlist.reduce(function(counts, word) {       
    counts[word] = (str.match(new RegExp(word, 'g')) || []).length;
    
    return counts;
  }, {});  
}

console.log(frequencies('foo foo bar foo   bar buz', ['foo', 'bar', 'zzz']));
```